# Change Rails Bootstrap body color

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the body background-color to a custom color. Usually I've written the custom css into the bootstrap_and_override.css file, which works, but with the body tag it doesn't. Some people here suggested finding and overriding the standard body css settings but sublime-text is, just as me, unable to find the corresponding line anywhere in the project.

Maybe I'm adressing the body tag wrong? I've written:

```
  body {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
  }
```

since the body tag doesn't seem to have any custom class by which it could be adressed. In chrome web inspector, I can see this, so it seems like my code is being noticed but later overwritten. But I just can't find the place where that happends.

[image: chrome analytics picture]

The crossed out background-color is the correct one, not #FFF.

I hope someone knows the answer to this, it can't be this hard? Thanks a lot!

**Update:**
Here is the content of the application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

**Update 2:**
Here is the content of the stylesheets folder: 
application.css 
bootstrap_and_overrides.css 
bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less 
... the rest are the site specific files, ending with .css.scss

Comment: This probably means that overrides file is not included AFTER main bootstrap files but before. Check your `application.css`

Comment: I haven't changed anything to the application.css file, what should I change there? Besides the description there are just these two lines:  `*= require_self
 *= require_tree .` (In two seperate lines)

Comment: Can you add content of `application.css`? And did you add this new body color at the END of `bootstrap_and_override.css`?

Comment: the new body is at the beginning but after that there comes nothing that changes the body back to something else.

Comment: Ok, so you use css versions, not less and the problem is as I expected. Files are included in wrong order. Can you add list of the files in `app/assets/stylesheets`?

Comment: I tried to use less but as I'm not experienced with it and the bootstrap less guide doesn't bring up any solution to change the body color, only link color and so on, I've tried it the css way.

Comment: LESS is just a superset of CSS which means there are some more things possible with it (variables, mixins). You don't need tutorial to change body color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `!important`. I would proceed with caution as this is not best practice. Forcing an override with `!important` has it's place and should be used only when necessary.

```
body {
    background-color: #F8F8F8 !important;
  }
```

An example of when I personally use `!important` is for debugging and to override rules set by javascript-generated inline CSS, if I do not have the permissions to edit the javascript/plugin.

Comment: Yes, that's why I left a comment and not -1.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but if it isn't recommended I would first try to do it the recommended way. I'm amazed there isn't a obvious standard way to change this, didn't the bootstrap creators think of it as necessary?

Comment: There is a standard way, but your css files are included in wrong order. The question is why, please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906809/change-rails-bootstrap-body-color?noredirect=1#comment26157472_17906809

Comment: @LinusAn Ensure you do not have a plugin installed that is applying the CSS on the fly and also note that your custom style has to be the last style called for that element on the page. Your custom stylesheet has to be the last style sheet included in the `<head>` and also the last declaration of `body` color on that particular sheet.

Comment: Ok, moving the body tag to the end of the bootstrap_and_overrides.css file didn't change anything. With the !important tag, it works.

Comment: If it's the last style added, and you are sure of it, then my assumption is that a javascript plugin is overriding it. In this instance `!important` is ok. Changing the plugin can cause other issues, especially if parts of the plugin are event driven based on declaration, and you then remove that declaration.

Comment: Ok thank you, I don't know of any plugin which would change the background, I go with important. Thanks again both of you!

Answer (score 0):

You must modifying the 'body' style in bootstrap css. The default is #fff (white). Beware because there are 2 'body' styles and the one on top is just for margin and the one in middle is for background color, font etc..